# translate tabledata in twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, language-translation

I fill my table with data in this way

```
  <tbody>
     {% for post in posts %}

            <tr>

              <td>{{ post.title }}</td>

              <td>{{ post.status }}</td>                

          </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

I need translate values from status, but it does not work. post.status has only 2 values in database **PO_DRAFT** and **PO_ACCEPT** and I need it translate. Is it possible?
I tried in this way but it is wrong

```
 <td>{% trans %}{{ post.status }}{% endtrans %}</td>
```

Comment: How about this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates

Answer (score 1):

Twig's [i18n documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html) mentions a `trans` filter, so maybe this would work?

```
{{ post.status | trans }}
```

Comment: it does not work too. I get this error: A message inside a trans tag must be a simple text in components/post/search.html.twig at line 89.